# When using LINQ to create a collection of IOrderedQueryable are you overriding the GetEnumerator method?

Tags: c#, linq, enumeration, iorderedqueryable

I understand that if you construct a LINQ query and append it with `.ToList()` you are executing that LINQ query there and then and returning a list object. However, if you don't do this, you instead get an IOrderedQueryable object which as I understand it, hasn't yet been sorted.

If I then place that collection into a For Each statement, is the list ordered at this point? And does this mean that I have in essence overridden the default implementation of GetEnumerator for that collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is known as **deferred** execution. What this basically entails is that as long as you don't call `ToList()`, `ToArray()` or any other method that casts your LINQ query directly to a collection, that query is executed at the moment the variable it is assigned to is *used*.

Up until the point to when your query is used, the `IEnumerable`is not enumerated. However, I don't think `GetEnumerator` overridden in the case of deferred execution.

Here's an MSDN blog regarding this specific subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the article I shall have a look. So I should see the deferred LINQ query as a separate sorting entity that doesn't rely on GetEnumerator but instead has its own way of sorting a collection when that collection is actually used (for example in a for each statement)?

Comment: Exactly, you could see it as a reference to the collection, to which the LINQ action is applied as soon as it is actually used.